# Retrofit 2 wait for response

Tags: android, asynchronous, retrofit2, android-networking

Got a problem with Retrofit 2, don't know if it's related to server bad response handling or to my code.

**USEFUL INFORMATIONS**

```
ApiUtils.getUserAPI(getApplicationContext());
```

Following code is inside getUserApi to create a proper OkHttpClient

```
 public static UserAPI getUserAPI(Context context) {
    String baseUrl = context.getString(R.string.base_context);
    if (gson == null) {
        gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();
    }
    if (okHttpClient == null) {
        okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .followRedirects(true)
                .followSslRedirects(true)
                .addInterceptor(new AddHeadersInterceptor())
                .addInterceptor(new ReceivedCookiesInterceptor())
                .build();
    }
    return new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseUrl).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)).client(okHttpClient).build().create(UserAPI.class);
}
```

Two interceptor adds some headers and sessionid cookie ( *I HAVE ADDED HEADERS TO SIMULATE REAL CALL*

```
HttpUrl url = chain.request().url();
    Request.Builder builder = chain.request().newBuilder();
    builder.addHeader("accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    builder.addHeader("accept-language", "it-IT,it;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,es;q=0.6,fr;q=0.5,ar;q=0.4");
    builder.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    builder.addHeader("origin", "https://www.XXX.XX");
    builder.addHeader("referer", url.toString());
    builder.addHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    List<String> cookies = SessionData.getInstance().getCookies();
    if (cookies != null && cookies.size() >= 1)
        builder.addHeader("Cookie", cookies.get(0).split(";")[0] + ";");
    return chain.proceed(builder.build());
```

Creation of a call

```
Call<ResponseBody> login = userAPI.login(user.getUserName(), user.getPassword());
```

Handling of response

```
login.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                try {
                    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(response.body().string());
                    if (doc.getElementsByClass("flash flash-error") != null && doc.getElementsByClass("flash flash-error").size() > 0) {
                        fullScreenOverlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), doc.getElementsByClass("flash flash-error").get(0).text(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        onLoginFail();
                    } else {
                       User user = ContentDeserializer.getInstance().parseNewUser(doc);
                        SessionData.getInstance().setUser(user );
                        onLoginDone(user );
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), getString(R.string.generic_error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    fullScreenOverlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
            } else {
                call.cancel();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), response.errorBody().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                fullScreenOverlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        }
```

Being no public API to retrieve code I have to simulate a mobile agent call and parse the content of the page to retrieve data.

**THE PROBLEM**

The problem is that with a slow connection ( I can reproduce forcing 2G connection for example) also if

```
 if (response.isSuccessful()) {
```

returns true when I parse data in the HTML content I found some div with

```
<span class="bt-label__state" data-button-state="submiting"> **Connecting** <span class="bt-icon bt-icon--loader"></span> </span>
```

If I switch to 4G or to a working connection the problem disappear

Seems like my page is not loaded but retrofit invoke as the page is loaded. It's a problem of the webpage giving me valid response codes ( as 200 or 302 - seen by developer tools in chrome) or there's something that I can do?

Comment: first of all you have to check your api call is working or not. you can check with "Postman" or "advance api rest client". if its return you expected output json object then you can check with your code. please check and let know

Comment: sorry @DinithePieris but no way your answer can help me. Request is working correctly as i recive body response from the server, sometimes with all data but in other cases the page contains code that suggests page is still loading